# Bq command or data flow for as is load

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a simple delimited file on gcs. I need to load that file as is(without transfermation) to bigqyery table. Either we can use data flow or bigqyery command line utility to load that file to bigqyery table. I need to understand which one is the best option bigqyery or bq command line utility.  Please consider factors like cost, performance etc before providing your valuable inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Running a BigQuery load using Dataflow or running it using bq command line is the same in terms of cost. Using bq load directly should be easier if you don't need to process the data.